# Windows Mobile - Internet Usage C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, opennetcf

I need to monitor internet traffic (both upload and download) on windows mobile. Is there any API available to monitor internet data traffic on windows mobile (C#)? I am using OpenNetCF in my project. I can also use API from OpenNetCF is it is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no API to monitor traffic (in managed or native code).  The best solution is to create an [NDIS intermediate filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee483408.aspx) that does all of the computations, stores the results and exposes an API for retrieving those results.  That has to be written in C.

Comment: @CirrusFlyer I have no idea about C language. Can you share your code?